# Use app.component function in a page ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to use `app.component.ts` function in a page, but getting **error**.

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.pages.updatePages')
```

Function in **app.component.ts**:

```
updatePages(pages){
   console.log(pages);
 }
```

Code in **page.ts**

```
this.sidebarpage = [{ title: 'My Account', component: MyAccountPage }];
this.pages.updatePages(this.sidebarpage);
```

Already imported component in page.ts and added `@ViewChild(MyApp) pages: MyApp;`

Answer (score 0):

app.component.ts is not a child page. [ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html) decorator is used when you are accessing a child component set in your corresponding html page and there is generally no need to use root tags in other pages.

You should create a provider class for this.
Set the function in the provider and set the class in providers array app.module.ts to use in your components.
[More here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)

Comment: Thank you for reply. But i have already defined some sidebar menus in component. Now i want to add one more item in the same array after login.

Comment: I just want to use component function in another page.